# Does GCP Cloud Build Docker remove files created during the Dockerfile execution?

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

I have a build step in the docker file that generates some files. Since I also need those files locally (when testing) I have the generation of them not in Cloud Build itself but in the Dockerfile (simple node script that executes via npx). Locally this works perfectly fine and my Docker image does contain those generated files. But whenever I throw this Dockerfile into Cloud Build it executes the script but it does not keep the generated files in the resulting image. I also scanned the logs and so on but found no error (such as a persission error or something similar).

Is there any flag or something I am missing here that prevents my Dockerfile from generating those files and storing them into the image?

Edit:

Deployment pipeline is a trigger onto a GitHub pull request that runs the cloud build.yaml in which the docker build command is located. Afterwards the image is getting pushed to the Artifact Registry and to Cloud Run. On Cloud Run itself the files are gone. Steps in-between I can't check but when building locally the files are getting generated and they are persistent in the image.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
ARG DISABLE_CLOUD_LOGGING
ARG DISABLE_CONSOLE_LOGGING
ARG GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./*.json ./
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./build ./build

ENV ENVIRONMENT="${ENVIRONMENT}"
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}"
ENV DISABLE_CLOUD_LOGGING="${DISABLE_CLOUD_LOGGING}"
ENV DISABLE_CONSOLE_LOGGING="${DISABLE_CONSOLE_LOGGING}"

ENV PORT=8080

RUN git config --global url."https://${GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com"
RUN npm install

RUN node ./build/generate-files.js
RUN rm -rf ./build

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT  [ "node", "./src/index.js" ]
```

Cloud Build (stuff before and after is just normal deployment to Cloud Run stuff)

```
...
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: [ '-c', 'docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=${_ENVIRONMENT} --build-arg  DISABLE_CONSOLE_LOGGING=true --build-arg GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN=$$GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN -t location-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/atrifact-registry/docker-image:${_ENVIRONMENT} ./' ]
  secretEnv: ['GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN']
...
```

Comment: We can only guess due to the lack of details on the build configuration. Rewrite your question showing what you are doing, the configuration files and the problem/result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Somehow the build process does not fail when crashing a `RUN` statement. This lead to me thinking there are no problem, when in fact it could not authorize my generation script. Adding `--network=cloudbuild` to the docker build command fixed the authorization problem.